# Can a VBA Macro be a function or only a sub?

Tags: vba, outlook

I imported a **`.bas`** file from https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Save-attachments-from-5b6bf54b but realized the function **`SaveAttachmentsFromSelection`** did not show up as a macro, for example in Ribbon menu Developer / Macros

It did show up after I changed it into a **`subroutine`**

Can VBA macros be functions?

Comment: Functions are like formulas, they should return something.  Subs do things, or multiple things.  You use a function to do repetitive things to return an outcome.  If your function does not return an item to what called it, then make it a sub.

Comment: @ScottCraner sorry for confusion. The function does return a value. My issue is that I do not see it in Outlook Macros list (for example in men path Develooper / Macros). This was a little surprising but the technet article says it should show up even as a function

Comment: You need to include the sub `ExecuteSaving()` in another standard module. The sub calls the function. Then you will be able to see the sub in the list of macros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The Macros dialog box only list non-private subroutine with no parameters.*

*Example*

```
Option Explicit
' this will show
Public Sub Public_Example()
    Debug.Print "Hello Public " ' print on immediate window
End Sub

' and this will show
Sub Public_Example()
    Debug.Print "Hello Public " ' print on immediate window
End Sub
```

*If you declare subroutine Private, function that return any value Or **Not** and subroutine with parameters will not show in the Macros dialog box*

*Examples*

```
Option Explicit
' this will not show
Public Sub Public_Example(Miserable As Integer)
    Debug.Print "Hello Private " ' print on immediate window
End Sub


' this will not show
Private Sub Private_Example()
    Debug.Print "Hello Private " ' print on immediate window
End Sub


' this will not show
Public Function Public_Example()
    Debug.Print "Hello Private " ' print on immediate window
End Function


' this will not show
Private Function Private_Example()
    Debug.Print "Hello Private " ' print on immediate window
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew about private subs and suspecting about the functions but I would have thought microsoft technet posts would be legit :)